# API Design for Validaion and Save scenarios

Tags: rest, api

I have an API where we want to save commercial breaks. There are also validations in terms of rules such as hour limit not breach, average duration with in limits etc.

Should such validations have a different endpoint such as POST commercialbreaks/validation and then we validate the same from UI

a. UI ->commercialbreaks/validation , if pass then UI hit commercialbreaks->POST /commercialbreaks.

b. or should we have a single endpoint i.e POST /commercialbreaks and then have /commercialbreaks/validation be called from inside inside this API.

Validation takes user input too for rules to validate against. We will have to pass the same whenever we hit POST /commercialbreaks if we go for b).

THere is a also a possibility that post validation there is a delay in save and then by then some changes have happened in system so we may need revalidation again.

Which is a better design approach. Also, we have a situation where Validation gives a message that it failed/passed and if user has the Override prvilige then he will be be able to override the validation and still be able to save the breaks. In this case should we have use the same endpoint POST /commercialbreaks with override flag =true/false. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do validation on a second endpoint, because you ALWAYS want the validation to run. You should do client-side validation in case you want to visualize problems before the user hits the save button. Then it should be server-side validation happening on that one endpoint. If validation fails, please note that you can return http status 400, but also return a JSON object if necessary with all infos about any remedy suggestions. I guess, validation is an implementation design topic and not an API design one.

Comment: thanks! the validation are based on external rules not domain specific so thats why we clarified.